# Get Files from document library with LINQ

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-enterprise, linq

Hi I'm trying to get file from a documentLibray with LINQ Query. 
I've been trying with this code but I get nothing!

```
 var allegatiCollegati = (from SPFile attach in web.Lists.["Allegati"].items

                         select attach ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var files = web.Lists["Allegati"].items
.Cast<SPListItem>()
.Where(item=>item.File!=null)
.Select(item=>item.File)
.ToList();
```

Comment: Remove dot between Lists and ["Allegati"]

Answer (score 1):

SPList.Items (web.Lists.["Allegati"].Items) returns an SPListItemCollection collection, which contains SPListItem and not SPFile objects. You can get the SPFile from the SPListItem by calling SPListItem.File.